# Any way to treat .* as .{0,1024} in perl RE?

Tags: regex, perl, optimization

We allow some user-supplied REs for the purpose of filtering email.  Early on we ran into some performance issues with REs that contained, for example, `.*`, when matching against arbitrarily-large emails.  We found a simple solution was to `s/\*/{0,1024}/` on the user-supplied RE.  However, this is not a perfect solution, as it will break with the following pattern:

```
/[*]/
```

And rather than coming up with some convoluted recipe to account for every possible mutation of user-supplied RE input, I'd like to just limit perl's interpretation of the `*` and `+` characters to have a maximum length of 1024 characters.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What part of an email do these filters run on? Headers, body?

Comment: @fge: Body is where this matters, because that's the part that can be arbitrarily large.  We do check on headers, too, but only one header at a time. And even the longest email headers aren't long enough to cause performance issues with * and +.

Comment: OK, then another question: do you run these regexes on the whole content, attachments included, or do you skip attachments?

Comment: @fge: We run it on all mime parts with a text-ish content type (text/plain, text/html, vcards, and a small handfull of others)

Comment: Disallow `*` and `+`, and instruct users to use `{n,m}` instead? That one has an upper limit of 32766.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Added a `(?<!\\)` before the quantifiers, because escaped *+ should not be matched. Replacement will still fail if there is an `\\*` (match `\` 0 or more times).

An improvement would be this

```
s/(?<!\\)\*(?!(?<!\\)[^[]*?(?<!\\)\])/{0,1024}/
s/(?<!\\)\+(?!(?<!\\)[^[]*?(?<!\\)\])/{1,1024}/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vg0g)

That means match `[*+]` but only if there is no closing `]` ahead and no `[` till then. And there is no `\` *(the `(?<!\\)` part)* allowed before the square brackets.

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead

`(?<! ... )` is a negative lookbehind

See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for details

**Update 2 include possessive quantifiers**

```
s/(?<!(?<!\\)[\\+*?])\+(?!(?<!\\)[^[]*?(?<!\\)\])/{1,1024}/   # for +
s/(?<!\\)\*(?!(?<!\\)[^[]*?(?<!\\)\])/{0,1024}/    # for *
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vg0j)

*Seems to be working, but its getting real complicated now!*

Comment: Yes, that is an improvement... it still leaves the case of the "possessive" + quantifier (i.e. `*+`, `++`, `?+`, and `{..}+`). I suppose I can form a similar recipe to ignore the + char in these cases, too.

Comment: Good point with the possessive quantifiers, added a solution for that.

Comment: Thanks... I completely identify with your last comment... *it is definitely getting complicated!*  I wish there was just a perlvar of $MAX_REGEXP_STRING_LENGTH or something! :)

Comment: @ikegami I stated that as restriction right at the top of my post.

Answer (score 5):

This does not really answer your question, but you should be aware of other issues with user-supplied regular expressions, see for example this [summary at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS). Depending on your exact situation, it might be better to write or find a custom simple pattern matching library?

Comment: +1, because `^(a|aa){0,30}$` is enough to keep the regex engine busy for millions of cycles with a string like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaX`

Comment: Thank you; a good warning.  Although it's certainly possible that a user can in effect DOS themselves, they could really only do it to themselves.  Thus our primary goal is to prevent them from doing this accidentally.

Comment: This does give me the idea to wrap all of my user-supplied REs in an `eval { alarm 1; ... };` block, though...

Answer (score 4):

Get a tree using [Regexp::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp%3a%3aParser) and modify regex as you want, or provide GUI interface to  [Regexp::English](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp%3a%3aEnglish)

Answer (score 1):

You mean except of patching the source?

1. You can break the input texts in shorter chunks and match only those. But then again, you wouldn't match over a "line" break.
2. You can break the regex, search only for the 1st char of it, load the next 1024 chars of text and then match the whole regex on this (obviously, that doesn't work with regex starting with .)
3. Find the first char of the regex that is not .*+()\, find that, load 1024 chars before and after and then match the whole regex on this string. (complicated and prune to errors in strange unforeseen regex)

Comment: yes... other than patching the source :)  (We still need the standard behavior in some cases that don't involve user-input)